# How do I get deboostrap (via live-build) to use Raspbian's release keyring?

Tags: debian, raspbian

I am trying to use live-build 5.0 on Debian squeeze to build a Raspbian live image. The `sudo lb build` command fails during the `debootstrap` phase, at the step:

```
I: Checking Release signature
E: Release signed by unknown key (key id 9165938D90FDDD2E)
```

I have tried (on the build system):

- installing the Raspbian repo key using `sudo apt-key add`
- manually installing `raspbian-archive-keyring_20120528.2_all.deb`
- adding the Raspbian key to `config/archives/raspbian.key.(binary|chroot)` (ie. from `/usr/share/keyrings/raspbian-archive-keyring.gpg`)
- prepending `DEBOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS="--keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/raspbian-archive-keyring.gpg"` to `lb config` and `lb build`
- same, but for `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg`
- including `--keyring-packages "raspbian-archive-keyring"` in my [auto/config](https://gist.github.com/detly/54e07c56f68b9d2ed066)

None of it worked. What do I need to do to tell debootstrap to use a different keyring? I don't want to tell it not to verify anything at all.

Comment: Try  
`wget https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key 
gpg --import raspbian.public.key
debootstrap --keyring /root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg`   

If the above fails then https://birchroad.wordpress.com/2012/06/09/raspbian-was-giving-me-a-pbuilder-rash/ may be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a very basic mistake. I was prepending `DEBOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS="--keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/raspbian-archive-keyring.gpg"` to `lb config && sudo lb build`, not realising that `sudo` does not allow environment variables through (because of the `Defaults env_reset` line in `sudoers`).

When I invoked with `sudo DEBOOTSTRAP_OPTIONS="--keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/raspbian-archive-keyring.gpg" lb build`, it was successful.

Answer (score 1):

As root run:

```
wget -qO - https://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian.public.key | gpg --import -
debootstrap --keyring /root/.gnupg/pubring.kbx ...
```